# change properties in array

Tags: c#, arrays, button

I have an array of Buttons.

When I try to change their back-Color it is not show at the web.

Why?

```
Button[] arr = new Button[2];
arr[0] = btn1;
arr[1] = btn2;

for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
{
   arr[i].backColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

but this is working good:

```
btn1.backColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

**Added from his answer:**

I am sorry, I wrote it from my head.

This is the problem code:

```
    static Button[] arr;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    arr = new Button[2];
    arr[0] = Button1;
    arr[1] = Button3;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    }
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

When I press Button1 it is work, but when I press Button2 it does not work..

Why?

Thanks

Comment: The code provided i technically equivalent, so I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: When the code to change the color of button objects in array is executed?

Comment: Dont you have to populate the `Button[]` array again in `Button2_Click` event?

Comment: How popilate it without create it over?

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint in the `Button2_Click` method? Is it hit? Does your array contain the two buttons? Is the `for`-loop executed properly?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

When you press Button2 before pressing Button1, the array of buttons is not created yet and therefore it can't set the color. Instantiate the array, for instace, in `Page_Load()`;

---

Also, I would suggest not to use arrays unless you are really sure you need them. Try this.

```
var btns = new List<Button> { btn1, btn2 };
```

If you want to add a new button, just call

```
btns.Add(btn3);
```

Coloring then looks, for instance, simple like this

```
foreach (var btn in btns)
   btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: clearly, the OP is not mentioning any compilation error, which shd imply 'backColor to be a typo for 'BackColor'. everything in your answer has nothing to do with OP's question

Comment: He does not mention it because clearly he does not know what it is. But it is obvious that he copied his code as it is. At least, I'm trying to help somehow to a beginner, not just slap him in comments.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek yes but you are only guessing with your answer. The information the op provided is really mediocre. And typos in code are somewhat normal for new users and should be commented before posting an answer

Comment: I am not copied this from anyone. this was from my head. see the other answer

Comment: @OrK Yeah, but it looked like so. Next time, pay attention before you post a question, please. Check my new answer based on your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

First of all decide when you want to change the backcolor of the button. On any button click event or page load, where ever you want to do just call below function. Your code is true. but just call set the button at second button click or always you have to click first button first.

```
public void ChangeColor()
{
    Button[] arr = new Button[2];
    arr[0] = btn1;
    arr[1] = btn2;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;         
    }
}
```

Update Answer as par your question.

```
Button[] arr;
protected void btnColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeColorRed();
}
protected void btnColor2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeColorGreen();
}
public void ChangeColorRed()
{
    SetButton();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
public void SetButton()
{
    arr = new Button[2];
    arr[0] = btn1;
    arr[1] = btn2;
}
public void ChangeColorGreen()
{
    SetButton();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Regards
AB Vyas

Comment: Yes! It's work. Thanks. But I want to know why with anoter function its work and why what I wrote is wrong.

Comment: Because every time you doing the SetButton()?

Comment: you didn't write any wrong. your code is right but you are missing to assign button array. You have to set the array then it will work fine other wise it will throw error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." :) if you got your solution just accept my answer.

Comment: @OrK Yes i just write down here more briefly so you can understand.

Comment: but if i dont want to create the array every time when i press btn2, just in the first time on btn1 (btn1 will press only one time). how can i do this?

Comment: @OrK just add SetButton() calling to  Page_Load() and remove it from clicking methods.

Comment: @OrK agree with Greage.Deay. You have to add SetButton method to the Page_Load() event of the page and remove from both button click event.

Comment: Put that array into the `Session` for the first time and just use it again and again.

Answer (score 0):

May be because you're showing btn1 and btn2?

Seems like you're creating copies of buttons.

How about this?

```
Button[] arr = new Button[2];
arr[0] = btn1;
arr[1] = btn2;

for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
{
   arr[i].backColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
   arr[i].Show(); //add Show
}
```

Comment: I dont have the Show() method

Comment: What is the significance of `Show` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I wrote it from my head.

This is the problem code:

```
    static Button[] arr;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    arr = new Button[2];
    arr[0] = Button1;
    arr[1] = Button3;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    }
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

When I press Button1 it is work, but when I press Button2 it does not work..

Why?

Thanks

Comment: i checked on my computer and it's allright, but you need to call button1 first

Comment: yes, i press btn1 and work good, and after btn2 and its stay blue